# Entity sql datetime literal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid-asp.net

I am stuck in the ObjectQuery class it always gives me the error as 
System.Data.Entity: The argument types 'Edm.DateTime' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation., near WHERE predicate

Please suggest me the solution, i followed the above approach, but it did not work.

my code is as follows:

C# code:

```
var _dbModel = new VISAIntBPAEntities();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Filters f = (!_search || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters)) ? null : serializer.Deserialize<Filters>(filters);
        //if (f != null)
        //{
        //    if (f.rules[0].field == "CreatedDate")
        //    {
        //        Convert.ToDateTime(f.rules[0].data).ToString();
        //    }
        //}
        ObjectQuery<Jobs> filteredQuery = (f == null ? _dbModel.Jobs : f.FilterObjectSet(_dbModel.Jobs));
        //if (f != null)
        //{
        //    if (f.rules[0].field == "CreatedDate")
        //    {
        //        filteredQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("CreatedDate", Convert.ToDateTime(f.rules[0].data)));
        //    }
        //}
        if (f != null)
        {
            DateTime dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(f.rules[0].data);
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where(string.Format("(it.CreatedDate = DATETIME'{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm}')", dateTimeValue));
        }
        filteredQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; // we don't want to update the data
        var totalRecords = filteredQuery.Count();
```

Cleint side code:

this code is in built using jqgrid, which has a column called CreatedDate, which fills in the dropdown, i have a sql query which fetches me the distinct date part from the database.
I am doing filtering based on the string date selection in the dropdown.

```
{
        name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', width: 140, stype: 'select', async: false, sorttype: 'date',
        edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: getCreatedJobDate() }, editable: true, formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
        //editrules: { required: true },
        searchoptions: {
        value: getCreatedJobDate,
        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'de']
        }
        }
```

Please help me as i am stuck with this approach, i need to do this way only.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The commented code show that you already experimented with `ObjectParameter`. You can do

```
filteredQuery = filteredQuery.Where("it.CreatedDate = @createDate");
var par = new ObjectParameter("createDate", dateTimeValue);
filteredQuery.Parameters.Add(par);
```

And the SQL code will show something like

```
DECLARE @createDate DateTime = '2002-11-06 00:00:00.000'
```

followed by the query itself.